# MFC- set a picture as a background image

Tags: c++, image, background, mfc

I am very confused.

I have a bitmap file. I just want to set it as my mfc background image. Unfortunately, the other relevant posts here are really confusing me. 
Can any of you describe in the **simplest** way you can how to set image from the Resources as a mfc background image(onInitDialog()...).

I am new to MFC and honestly find it very hard.
Thanks in advance!

In contrast to other similar questions I am looking for a way with the VS2019 Function SetBackgroundImage/something easier to implement...

Comment: Seems to handle the `WM_PAINT` message is the easiest (best, simplest?) way.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: It's answered in the duplicate questions in more detail.

Comment: I read them, but can't i just do:
 this->SetBackgroundImage(IDB_BITMAP1, BACKGR_TILE, TRUE);

Comment: Well, if it doesn't work, ditch it.

Comment: but how do i link to my bmp?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221174/discussion-between-codelearner-and--).